# Navigation Drawer onDrawerSlide change Alpha Api 11

Tags: android, sdk, navigation-drawer, alpha

I want to set down the Alpha of the Toolbar while the Navigation Drawer is opended and reset it when it is closed. On lower Api than 11 .setAlpha do not work. I tried this :

```
 public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
                final AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1 - slideOffset, 0.6f);
                animation.setDuration(0);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                toolbar.startAnimation(animation);
            } else if (slideOffset < 0.6) {
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
            }
        }
```

On Andorid 5.0 everything work. But if I close the NavDrawer on Android 2.3 the alpha is not reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
just do add the following line in onDrawerClosed function 

toolbar.clearAnimation();


@Override

 public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {``
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                toolbar.clearAnimation();
            }
```